# text.startswith method with multi words

Tags: python, list, text, startswith

Hello I want to use the `.startswith` method, but I could only get it to work with one word.
I want more than one word.

For example what I did:

```
if text.startswith('welc')
   print('Welcome')
```

but I wanted:

```
list = ['welc', 'hey', 'sto']

if text.startswith(list)
   print('It works')
# This doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any()`:

```
>>> s = "welcome"
>>> l = ['welc', 'hey', 'sto']
>>> any(s.startswith(i) for i in l)
True
```

Comment: @Frederik yup, but converting the list to a tuple and passing to `startswith()` as kindall and Sukrit Kalra suggested looks better.

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) says, the argument must be a tuple. Oddly, lists do not work. So:

```
text = "welcome"
greets = ("welc", "hey", "sto")

if text.startswith(greets):
    print("Welcome")
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for startswith() says that you can pass it a tuple of strings e.g.

```
list = ('welc', 'hey', 'sto')
```

and passing this to the startswith() leads to the output True.  But it does not tell you which word it was that returned True.  If you wan't to know that you can use a loop.